Binding chart not working when using ApexCharts at a flowbite svelte projects
I want to use the ApexCharts method at a flowbite svelte projects, but it does not work
I followed the sample code from
https://flowbite-svelte.com/docs/plugins/charts#Binding_chart
It is not working, i added alert(chart); before chart.updateSeries(series);
It shows chart is undefined.
Also i got error at <Chart {options} bind:chart />
The error states the options are not assignable to type 'ApexOptions'
(I don't know if this is the reason, but I can run fine on other chart's examples along with this error)
